# Error: file not found: arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo

Tags: android

I am trying to build android project

Getting below error even after setting correct path for toolchains

```
/bin/sh: lzop: not found
  AS      arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo.o
arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo.S: Assembler messages:
arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo.S:4: Error: file not found: arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.lzo.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux] Error 2
make: *** [zImage] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/workspace/android/kernel/exynos54xx'
build: error: build-kernel failed and die !!!
```

Comment: It worked wit below,  it seems to be ur tool chain issue. Try like this
  sudo apt-get install lzop

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution if you're using Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lzop
```

or look for the lzop package of you OS.